# PersistGate causes the app to stop rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I am in the process of configuring a React Native app with Redux store and `PersistGate`. The Redux store is configured and working as expected, but the `PersistGate` is causing the app to stop rendering even the first screen. Without `PersistGate` the app renders fine.

Here is the `App.js` code:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
    import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
    import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';
    import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
    import allReducers from './store/reducers/index';

    const store = createStore(
      allReducers,
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
      //compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), autoRehydrate()),
    );

    // This line makes store persistent.
    const persistor = persistStore(store);

    type Props = {};
    export default class App extends Component<Props> {
      componentDidMount() {
        if (SplashScreen) {
          SplashScreen.hide();
        }
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={ store }>
            <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                <AppNavigator />
            </PersistGate>
          </Provider>
        );
      }
    }
```

The Reducer index file:

```
    import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
    import userReducer from './UserReducer';
    const allReducers= combineReducers({
      user: userReducer,
    });
    export default allReducers;
```

If I remove the `<PersistGate persistor={persistor}>` tag from `App.js` file, the app works fine. But when I use the `PersistGate`, I just see a white screen without any crash.

What am I missing which causes this weird output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to call the persistReducer function:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
let persistor = persistStore(store)
```

More info in their doc: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: That worked, but the store still loses the values after reload

Comment: Maybe check the persistConfig storage options, I never did it in React Native only in React